# Browser Automation and Cross Site Scripting

Tags: automation, xss

I'm trying to write some web-based automation.  The sites I'm hitting aren't on the same domain as my automation, so cross-site scripting issues make it impossible to access the DOM on the target website.

I don't want to use a proxy or deal with proxifying the target websites (like Selenium does, for example).  Cross-platform is a nice to have, but isn't a must.  I'll go Windows only if I'm forced to.

I realize I could simply write a Windows program that runs a WebBrowser control and my own set of scripts, but I don't want my users having to download an EXE from my webpage, or any registry overrides to disable cross-domain checking.  It has to be extremely easy to use, no extra software downloads or anything.

I tried to write an ActiveX control which includes the MS WebBrowser control, so I could have a "browser-in-a-browser", so to speak.  This didn't work.  I ended up with winocc.cpp assertion failures.

What other options do I have?  Would a Java applet work?  I'd need a Java-based browser.. would I have to look at using JRex or Lobo?

There has just got to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a server-side language to obtain the external page using a screen scrape. I've done this using PHP and also in C#.NET, but you could use pretty much any server side language to make a web request that returns the whole chunk of HTML from the target page.

Once you have the HTML, you can do what you want with it, as it's just a string that you're going to manipulate in some way and then write on your page.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that because I'm trying to build automation, the browser client needs to maintain an interactive session with the target website, which may include cookies.  That means I'd have to spend a lot of effort going down the proxy path to get everything on the server.  Is there no way to do this on the client?

Comment: Not really - until you download and install something on the client to do it. You can improve that experience with click-once deployments though.