# Auto populate form fields on external sites from local MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, autocomplete

Howdy folks, I am wanting to build a script or something to take a single row from my MySQL database and use that data to pre-populate form fields on one of multiple sites that aren't mine. What I'd like to do is to take information a user has entered on my site and when they click a link to one of the sites in my system it loads the external site with certain pre-mapped fields populated with the info they entered. But I can't seem to get my head around a way to do this, seeing as I can't add anything to these pages. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: The only way you could do something like this would be with the help of a browser add-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow you described is not possible due to cross-site scripting constraints.  This post is relevant: [Browser Automation and Cross Site Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818482/browser-automation-and-cross-site-scripting)

The closest thing I can think of is [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), which would force the user to download the plugin from Mozilla, plus a new userscript from your website.

Another option would be reproducing the form on your own web server, and hoping the `form action` doesn't perform referrer checks.

Comment: This is what I've figured. Greasemonkey would work because this is all in house stuff, I can install it on the computers the users use. Could you direct me to where I can get more information on doing this using Greasemonkey?

Comment: Your best bet is the Tutorials section on GreaseSpot: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials#Greasemonkey_tutorials

Comment: If I were writing it, the script would perform a call to your API (I recommend JSONP), which exposes information from the database (e.g. GET http://yourdomain.com/your_api/formFields?user_id=15211), and the script would use that response to populate the form on the destination site.

Answer (score 0):

i am not very sure but you can use `wget` and pass xml data...i.e you can build an xml string with the data you want to send across and then do a wget to the other site...hope this helps